# Put String to JSONObject wrong value

Tags: android

I try to put image saved in base64 to JSONObject. Everything is ok but when I put String to jsonobject: `verificationDataPersonal.put("file_data", imageObj.getFile_data());` before every "/" i get sign "\". So in String I have value: `/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...` and when i put string to json I get: `\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRg...` There is any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a problem, maybe the first "\" is an escape sequence, isn't it?
Have you proved to convert it back from JSON to String to see if it comes back ok?